# Splitting a string on a number

Tags: lua

If I have a string such as `"123abc456def"` how could I put that into a table like `{"123abc","456def"}` (splitting on the number, but keeping it).

I have found `string.match()`, but that removes the letter it is split on, at least with the patterns (Is that the right word?) I have been using, but I don't know how to make them myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use `gmatch` on the pattern `%d+%a+`, which matches a sequence of numbers followed by letters:

```lua
t = {}
s = "123abc456def"
count = 0
for m in string.gmatch(s, "%d+%a+") do
    t[count] = m
    count = count + 1
    print(m)
end
```

This prints:

```
123abc
456def
```